# Deleting/Ignoring Duplicate Records In A Table And Keeping Only the Earliest Ones

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need an SQL query to remove the duplicates in the following picture. Suppose the name of the table is "Opens".
[image]

As you can see there are so many records that are almost identical in Id,SendQueueId,SubscriberId and Email. The only thing that is different is their DateTime. I need to only select one from each Id so that my Ids will be unique and only keep the earliest one.

Comment: ...you probably don't want to be showing people's email addresses on the internet.

Comment: @anaximander you probably want to find a solution to the problem cz that's why i'm here.

Comment: A little uncalled for... If I have a solution, I'll post it, but in the meantime I'm just trying to help you by pointing out that the owners of those email addresses might not want them posted online like that. No need to snap.

Comment: @anaximander thanks, i'll be careful next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Common Table Expression to identify duplicates using the `ROW_NUMBER` function and delete all occurrences outside of whichever you designate as the "first" one.

```
;with cte as (
  select *, 
    row_number() over (
      partition by Id, SendQueueId, SubscriberId, Email, WP_CampaignId
      order by DateTime
    ) as RN
  from
    Opens
)

delete
  cte
where
  RN > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

another suolution with standard sql:

> ```
> delete from opens a
>  where not exists
>  (Select *
>           From (select Id,
>                        SendQueueId,
>                        SubscriberId,
>                        Email,
>                        WP_CampaignId,
>                        min(date_time) date_time
>                   From opens
>                  group by Id, SendQueueId, SubscriberId, Email, WP_CampaignId) b
>          Where a.id = b.id
>            and a.SendQueueId = b.SendQueueId
>            and a.SubscriberId = b.SubscriberId
>            and a.Email = b.Email
>            and a.WP_CampaignId = b.WP_CampaignId);
> ```